# ruby hash setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found this in my some code I was working on and I was wondering what this is doing

```
h = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = 0}
 => {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a block is passed to `Hash.new` that block is called each time a non-existent key is accessed. Eg:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Default" }
h[:defined_key] = "Example"    

puts h[:defined_key] # => "Example"
puts h[:undefined_key] # => "Default"
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718 for more detail.

Comment: Oh, cool. This is the first time I've seen that feature of a Hash.

Comment: Important to realize that this is going to set the value of 0 for any keys that is *checked*. That's quite a side-effect for an action that otherwise has no repercussions, so as a result I usually recommend against this. Often better to catch the nil cases at the point where you're asking, like `x = h.key?(y) ? h[y] : 0` or `x = h[y] || 0`.

Comment: Unless, of course, that side-effect is exactly why you've declared the hash that way in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718

This block defines what the hash does when accessing a nonexistent key.  So if there is no value for a key, then it sets the value to 0, and then returns 0 as the value.

It's not just good for defaults - you could have it throw an exception of there is no such key, for example.  In fact, if you just want a default value, you can say:

```
Hash.new "defaultValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its making the default values for any new keys equal to zero instead of nil, observe the test in and irb console session:

```
$ irb
>> normal_hash = Hash.new
=> {}
>> normal_hash[:new_key]
=> nil
>> h = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = 0}
=> {}
>> h[:new_key]
=> 0
```